# Debian 10 won't boot after installation on Lenovo ideapad 100S-14IBR

Tags: linux, debian, debian-buster

I tried installing Debian 10 on my Lenavo ideapad 100S-14IBR laptop. However, I am not able to boot the OS when starting up. I was able to get some pictures of the startup. Please find them below. However, I was able to use Debian 9.9 without any issues.

Would anyone be able to help regarding this?

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael
[image: img1[![img2[![img3[![img4[![img5]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDUk5.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKguk.jpg)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee2gw.jpg)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW7v5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[debian.org](https://www.debian.org/) has seems to fix this issue. I did this installation about 6 months ago on my `Lenavo ideapad 100S-14IBR` laptop. However, I installed a debian 10 by upgrading from debian 9.9 and also through a clean installation of debian 10 it seems to work fine now without an issue.

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael